# printing properties with Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to print `Object's` own properties (not including `prototype` properties) by using `Object.keys()` method.

```
var obj = {
    name : "Jane"
}

keys = Object.keys(obj); //["name"]
```

when I do

```
console.log("length" in keys) //It is printing true?
```

I believe `"length"` is coming from the `prototype`. Why does it exist in `keys` array?

Comment: You are confusing the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) with the [`includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) of arrays. `length` is a property of `keys`, not of `obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it exist in keys array?

It does exists in `keys array` since `keys` is an instance of **Array** and Array has the property `length`.

This is equivalent of saying

```
if ( "length" in keys)
{ 
  console.log(true)
}
```

Check [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) documentation here too.

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.

Comment: If you want to add [_The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).. Not quiet sure about _"It checks the prototype of Array"_

Comment: It does exist in the keys array. Array instances have their own length property. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length

Comment: @FizzyTea Corrected my post, I didn't articulated properly what I inteded to say earlier. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys()` returns an `Array` and [Arrays always have length property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length).

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) Documentation.

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).